# Processing digital sound in Audiokit to sound like the 1960's

Tags: filters, audio, filtering, digital, analog

I am looking to imitate 70's analog equipments sound. I was wondering is there a way to create tape saturation / distortion inside Audiokit? I want to add that and randomized tape crackles and artifacts to the mix which I know is possible in AudioKit luckily.

From what I understand Tape Simulator plugins normally distort the lower frequencies more than than the high which might be possible in AudioKit if I create multiple audio streams (Lower end, higher end) using equalization and distort the lower end more. Is there a way to make the curve of the sound more linear?

[How to model Tape Saturation (Audio DSP)?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/17526/how-to-model-tape-saturation-audio-dsp)

Analog tape sounds further back in the virtual 3d space than digital. To achieve that I typically slightly cut off the higher end with a curve in parametric equalizers and add a convolution reverb to imitate natural space. Tape also has a much smoother smaller range for low frequencies which maybe I will cut off with a low pass filter.

I was wondering if anyone has anymore knowledge to achieve an effective tape simulation and to get a very retro sound in Audiokit? I am making a video camera app full of retro filters with grain and artifacts. It would be awesome if I could also have the sound feel retro as well.

This is my ideal clip for a frame of reference how audio sounded back then. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hEpSVCYok8s